# How to type custom React hooks that are created in JS and used in a TSX file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that is unfortunately written in pure JS that I am using in a TypeScript .tsx file.

I'm calling it like

```js
const [toggleDictation, dictationResults] = useDictation()

  useEffect(() => {

    //start recognizing
    toggleDictation();

  }, []);
```

I get an error in the compiler that says:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'string | boolean | never[] | (() => Promise<void>)' are callable.
    Type 'string' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

the toggleDictation function in the custom JS hook is written as:

```js
  const toggleDictation = async () => {
    try {
      if (!speechHasStarted) {
        await _startRecognizing();

        return;
      } else {
        await _stopRecognizing();
        return;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error("Error in toggleDictation, ", e);
      return;
    }
  };
```

Is there a way to typecast or assert this to set the function type correctly to remove the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem here is with the `useDictation` function. By default, even in typescript a function returning an array is an array not a tuple type.

```
const toggleDictation = async () => { }
const useDictation = () => { // returns Array<(() => Promise<void>) | never[]>
    return [toggleDictation, []]
}

const [tg, arr] = useDictation(); // tg is (() => Promise<void>) | never[] so uncallable
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=89&pln=1&pc=1#)

In ts you can add an `as const` or an explicit type annotation to fix this:

```
const toggleDictation = async () => { }
const useDictation = () => { // returns Array<(() => Promise<void>) | never[]>
    return [toggleDictation, []] as const
}

const [tg, arr] = useDictation(); // tg is now () => Promise<void>
tg() // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIHMEBsCmARAlsKBDKm4MAvDLhAJ5jAwAUAlCQHwwDeMAvgFCiSwCuEDNjwEipBszYwA9DJgAnVFH4LIMAIIKFuCgB5ak4iwAKCkAFtMQvQDcQmACZNGAHxhhUt1AoDaAXSYuGBDFZVUwGF94JDQsHHxCMAAaKP9-MggYXmgubh5waCioBFTcbQzSQWEEsTAGAG5ZeRKYaw8QAHc6RmMYM0trVDsHZy4SyTkYEABrLnmuIA)

For JS we have some options, if you control the js, you can add jsdoc types and they will be picked up by TS:

```
const toggleDictation = async () => { }

/**
 * @returns {[()=> Promise<void>, string[])]}
 */
const useDictation = () => {
    return [toggleDictation, []]
}

let [tg, d] = useDictation(); // tg is ()=> Promise<void>
tg() // ok in ts as well
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1&useJavaScript=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIHMEBsCmARAlsKBDKm4MAvDLhAJ5jAwAUAlCQHwwDeMAvgFBcD0AVPy4x+MAAIAnVFACuEyGwDaDYiwAKEkAFtMEVAB4AbiEwATJgBoY0CZjAJFAXXqPuI3l1CRYMvVhz4hGAkdIyqbMIwUVKy8jCK8Eho-ngE4FZOjlzcXGiwCQhWpo4hvhjYqUEMANwwvLxwCDC6oeEa2roGxmZMXFAIDHUNIADWzcFQEGRTAO6oyMgwPFxAA)

Or you can add a declaration file, but that really depends on  your setup. If you create a declaration for a module, you will not get any more inference from js. You could generate a `d.ts` from the js files (available since 3.7 [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32372)) and correct any declarations (such as the return type of `useDictation`)

```
declare const useDictation : () => [()=> Promise<void>, string[]]

let [tg, d] = useDictation(); // tg is ()=> Promise<void>
tg() // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#)

Answer (score 1):

Typing this shouldn't have an impact on the compiled result.
Of course, if this works in a plain JS file, what i'm saying is false, but the problem seems to lie in the implementation rather than the lack of typing.